# Configuration changes in Android and which variables to save in the instance state

Tags: android, configuration, instance

I'm trying to understand configuration changes and instance state a bit better.

Right now I know that an action such as rotating the screen is considered a configuration change, which destroys and recreates the activity. Sometimes this means that if you aren't careful you may lose values (for example if you had a list of numbers that gets reset to all 0's when you rotate the screen).

There are usually methods you can use such as `onSaveInstanceState`, or `onRestoreInstanceState`, or checking if `savedInstanceState` is null or not in the `onCreate` method, etc -- for saving and restoring values so you don't lose anything when something changes.

My questions:

1. Are there multiple types of configuration changes that need to be taken into account? For example if I get my app to work as expected even with screen rotations, does this also imply that it will carry over and act as expected with other forms of configuration changes?
2. How do I know which variables I should be saving into my instance state variable and which will be auto-preserved when a configuration change takes place? Is it good practice to store all your member variables in the instance state in `onSaveInstanceState` and then re-apply them in `onRestoreInstanceState`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For example if I get my app to work as expected even with screen rotations, does this also imply that it will carry over and act as expected with other forms of configuration changes?

Generally, yes. I would phrase it more as: a well-implemented approach to configuration changes will handle all possible configuration changes.

So, for example, if the user runs your app, presses HOME, goes into Settings, changes their locale, then returns to your app through the overview screen (a.k.a., recent-tasks list), your top-most activity will undergo a configuration change. The goal here is for you to load in fresh string resources and stuff, to reflect the newly-chosen language. But, if you save some user-facing string in the saved instance state `Bundle` and simply use that string in the new activity — instead of calling `getString()` again — then you will have a value from the old language.

Many developers only think of orientation changes. *Usually*, if you handle an orientation change, all other configuration changes are handled "for free". But, that's not always the case, which is why you need to think it through.

> How do I know which variables I should be saving into my instance state variable and which will be auto-preserved when a configuration change takes place?

The primary things that are "auto-preserved" are:

- the `Intent` that was used to start the activity
- user-mutable state in widgets in your UI (e.g., text in an `EditText`)... assuming that either you do not override `onSaveInstanceState()` or chain to the superclass implementation

If you are using fragments, your fragments will either be retained (i.e., same instances used) or re-created (i.e., fresh instances of the same class used) on a configuration change.

What is *not* handled automatically are any fields/data members of your activity. Those you need to decide:

- Is this something that I need to hold onto across a configuration change, or is it merely a cache for something to be rebuilt in the new activity?
- Is this something that I can reasonably put in the saved instance state `Bundle`, or is it of a size (e.g., `Bitmap`) or data type (e.g., `Socket`) that cannot be held onto that way? For these, you will need to pursue other techniques besides the saved instance state `Bundle` (retained fragment, persisting the data, etc.).

Comment: For something like a Bitmap couldn't I apply it to an ImageView to have it persist?

Comment: And what about custom objects that are private members of the class? I'd assume you'd always have to take these into account, either by having them implement Parcelable, or use the slower Serializable (which doesn't require all the extra code in the classes AFAIK)?

Comment: @SeanHill: "couldn't I apply it to an ImageView to have it persist?" -- no. A user cannot directly put an image in an `ImageView`. That is not "user-mutable state", and so the built-in `onSaveInstanceState()` implementation ignores it, just as it ignores things like visibility, enabled/disabled, and so it. If the user can change the state on her own (e.g., checking a `CheckBox`, sliding a `SeekBar`), then there's a decent chance that such state is handled by Android (though there are some gaps).

Comment: @SeanHill: "what about custom objects that are private members of the class?" -- as I wrote, "What is not handled automatically are any fields/data members of your activity". That is true regardless of whether those fields are simple primitives, collections, instances of your own classes, or whatever.

Comment: In your app that you linked me in another question, in https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/master/Camera/Content/app/src/main/java/com/commonsware/android/camcon/CameraContentDemoActivity.java I notice that you restore things in `onCreate` by checking if the instance state is null or not. Is there a reason you handle this in `onCreate` and not in `onRestoreInstanceState`?

Comment: @SeanHill: Because I want to invoke `startActivityForResult()` before the end of `onCreate()`, so I need my `output` value before then.

Answer (score 2):

1. onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState could be called when the Android OS is running low on memory and it needs to kill some processes.  For example, if you app enters the background and is later resumed, these methods could be called.
2. All Views are automatically saved by the Activity.  For instance, an EditText's text and a checkbox's checked state will be saved and restored automatically after a configuration change.  All other data (including instance variables) for the Activity should be saved by you manually using the onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState methods.

Comment: So basically any non-View data structure (such as Strings, ints, Lists, custom objects, etc) that are members would need to be manually saved/restored?

Comment: Does this also imply that it is good practice to make all my objects implement Parcelable?

Comment: @SeanHill You've got it!

Comment: Not all Views, the text of a TextView will be reset to the initial value (from the xml file).

Comment: @0X0nosugar That's a good point.  If you programmatically change the text of a TextView it will not be restored automatically.